# Understanding computation graph

Tags: graph, x86, intel

I'm trying to understand micro-ops and computation graphs for intel architecture. I have the following graph :
[image]

With the standard 6 functional units: 1 load, 1 store, 2 integer, and 2 floating point, can the machine execute the given execution graph? 
My answer is yes, because there is only one integer op per each cycle. What I'm not sure about are load ops. I know that they can be pipelined, but don't know if that can be done three at a time. I would like to know if this can be done. Thanks.